# Dynamically generate an SQL `WHERE` query, from a `View` in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am working on a back-up application with **Laravel 5** and I have an issue.

I have to use the entered information from a *View*, so I can generate a **SELECT *  query**. The problem is that, **WHERE**, should be dynamic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfV3z.png

Like, in the link above, where I show my query, the query I tried using is this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ch1 < 1 AND ch2 = 2;`

Comment: I wish I could say this was the first time someone drew an SQL query in MS Paint and posted it here.

Comment: I'm surprised i actually understood what you're trying to say. Unfortunately this isn't a place where people write code for your requirements. Start by learning how to use forms to send request data and use that to craft the sql query with dynamic conditions.

Comment: People would be a lot more receptive if you showed what code you have attempted and what problem you are encountering.

Comment: thanks guys for ur response i understand what are u sayong ..i just need to start first ..i know what should i do but how is the probleme ..i will try to write a code and post here ...

Comment: here is the code..that do this and it's working

Comment: public function generateSql($table)
{$details = HistParams::where('table_name',$table)->get();

 if (isset ($details))
 {
  $first = true;
  $SQL="SELECT * FROM ".$table ;
  foreach($details as $detail)
  {
   $table_name= $detail ->table_name;
   $champ= $detail->field_name;
   $operand=$detail->operand;
   if($first)
   {
   $SQL .= " WHERE ";
   }else 
    $SQL .= " AND ";
     $first = false;
   if ($operand=='8')
   {$val_1=$detail ->value_1;$val_2=$detail ->value_2;
$SQL .= "between ".$val_1." and ".$val_2 ;
   }if ($operand=='7')
   {$SQL .= "IS NOT NULL ";
   }}

Answer (score 0):

Why you are building the sql query by yourself?

It is better to use the Query builder of Laravel `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:

Ex.:

```
$query = \DB::query();
$query->from($table);

foreach ($details as $detail)
{
    $query->where($detail->field_name, $detail->operand, $detail->value);
}
```

you can read mor about the query builder [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)